# Moving Angular 2 app from Windows 10 to Mac OS X: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, webpack

I am moving my nodejs app development from Windows 10 to Mac and am only vaguely familiar with OS X and am feeling my way through. I am using npm 3.6.0 and webpack to build and Angular 2 beta 3 static HTML, Javascript, CSS etc. which will call an API running in a separate nodejs application hosted somewhere in the cloud. Someone else is responsible for developing this API.

I am having a problem inasmuch the browser is complaining that it can't find the jQuery library in one of my routes. The complaint in Chrome looks like this:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

The code for the route looks like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';
import { ControlGroup, FormBuilder, AbstractControl, Validators } from 'angular2/common';
import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector: 'signin',
directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
styles: [require('../../../sass/signin.scss').toString()],
template: require('./signin.component.html')
})
export class SignInComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('rememberMeElement') rememberMeElement;

    signinForm: ControlGroup;
    emailOrUsername: AbstractControl;
    password: AbstractControl;
    rememberMe: AbstractControl;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        require('jquery');
        require('../../../js/jquery.icheck.min.js');
        require('../../../css/checkbox/orange.css');

        this.signinForm = fb.group({
            "emailOrUsername": ["", Validators.required], 
            "password": ["", Validators.required],
            "rememberMe": ["", Validators.required]
            }
        );

        this.emailOrUsername = this.signinForm.controls['emailOrUsername'];
        this.password = this.signinForm.controls['password'];
        this.rememberMe = this.signinForm.controls['rememberMe'];
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // nasty legacy stuff
        jQuery(this.rememberMeElement.nativeElement).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-orange',
            radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-orange',
            increaseArea: '20%'
        });    
    }
}
```

I have tried requiring jQuery outside of the class declaration - in fact, that's how I originally had it - but that makes no difference to the error. I have lifted this signin router code from an application that works, although that was running on Windows.

Can anyone tell me how I might require jQuery in order to get this to work? I might try requiring jQuery like `jQuery = require('jquery')` and see how this works but for some reason my Mac is trying to reboot and I don't want to lose this post!

Comment: Isnt it better to create an attribute directive where you can access `rememberMeElement.nativeElement` and call iCheck there? than you can use it anywhere, and you will call jQuery in ngOnInit() function. Nothing connected with the answer but just wondering

Comment: Probably Denko, but I have a million and one things I'd like to change about this app and I'm developing a throwaway demo